# Making a directory and moving files into that directory that match a pattern

Tags: bash, exec

I can pattern match files and move them into a directory using the line below.  But I need to make the directory first.

(**must make testdir directory first**)

```
find . -type f -name '*-bak*' -exec mv '{}' ./testdir ';'
```

What I'm trying to do now is have the line of code **also create the directory** and move the files that match that pattern into that directory using the same line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mkdir -p testdir && find . -type f -name '*-bak*' -exec mv {} testdir/ ';'
```

Be careful though, if you get two backups with the same name in different folders, you'll only be left with a single copy and all other copies overwritten!

EDIT: use `mv -i` to get prompted in that case instead of overwriting the files